# Django: uploaded image is not showing in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to write a simple blog using a Django framework. I want to have a cover image for a every post.

I uploaded an image via Admin site and everything seems to be fine but image is not rendering in a browser.

Here is my files:

**models.py**

```
(...)
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/%Y/%m/", blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
(...)
```

**django_blog_project\urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**blog\urls.py**

```
(...)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^posts/create/$', PostCreate.as_view(), name="post_create"),
    url(r'^posts/([\w-]+)/$', AuthorPostList.as_view(), name="posts_by_author"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    url(r'^', PostListView.as_view(), name="post_list"),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
(...)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
(...)
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" >
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    <p>Autor: {{ post.author }}</p>
    <p>Opublikowano: {{ post.modified }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**Dir tree**

[My directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNCXX.jpg)

**URL of the image resolving to**

```
<img src="/media/images/2016/12/fotolia_97812586.jpg">
```

Comment: When you inspect the page, what is the url of the image resolving to?

Comment: @WesDoyle URL is 
'<img src="/media/images/2016/12/fotolia_97812586.jpg">'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `$` char in pattern solved a problem.

**blog\urls.py**

```
(...)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^posts/create/$', PostCreate.as_view(), name="post_create"),
    url(r'^posts/([\w-]+)/$', AuthorPostList.as_view(), name="posts_by_author"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    # url(r'^', PostListView.as_view(), name="post_list"), # WRONG! 
    url(r'^$', PostListView.as_view(), name="post_list"),  # CORRECT! 
]
```